# access one file by two different names

Tags: files, shortcuts

I have a snippets file in my vim bundle folder that I use to keep some snippmate snippets. My jade templating language is currently going through a name change from jade to pug (ahhh). Anywho, I want to make a pug.snippets file, that is just a shortcut or reference to jade.snippets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Assuming you want the shortcut in the same directory, open a terminal, `cd` to the directory where `jade.snippets` lives and:

```
ln -s jade.snippets pug.snippets
```

Now if you have a program that looks for `pug.snippets` it will find `jade.snippets`. If you call a text editor to write to `pug.snippets` (eg `nano pug.snippets`), you will actually be editing `jade.snippets`.

Your symlink looks something like:

```
$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 you you 10 Aug 7 pug.snippets -> jade.snippets
```

N.B. If you delete the symlink, the original file will not be affected, but if you delete the original file or move it, the symlink will be broken - it's just a name and location and text string pointing to the location of the regular file.

Comment: Might want to add "open a terminal".

Comment: So, the first file in the command is the actual file, and the second is its symlink? But I can interact with either or, and I'm interacting with the original? That's pretty sweet, thanks!

Comment: correct :) yes it is a great feature... I was going to add a little NB as a comment but I added it to my answer instead :)